# How can I download my disc games onto PS4 without needing to put discs in again?

Tags: ps4

Are there ways to download a game onto your PS4 so you don't need the disc without paying for it on the store?

Answer (score 16):

No, otherwise people would do this and then return or redistribute the discs

Comment: I thought most retailers do not accept opened discs as returns. The logic seems to be more around the resale of discs, or, the “circulating disc” where one person buys the game and lets ten other people use it. Either way, downloading the game from disc would certainly be abused by many and thereby lower physical copy sales.

Comment: @ARich there's also PS4 game disc rental service somewhere out there.

Comment: Actually yeah by 'return' I was making the assumption of a rental but I guess that business isn't as big as it used to be